# Problem with position of labels on bar plot in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to have all labels with values just next to the bars. One of the bars has negative value and it creates a problem with position_dodge. I cannot set it how I like using hjust, because the label on the bar with negative value is placed in a completely different place.
How am i supposed to solve this problem?

Dataset: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeHhi.jpg (I don't have enough reputation to attach it to the post)

```
ggplot(USA, aes(x = Values, 
                y = fct_reorder(factor(Categories), Values),
                fill = Categories)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.65) +
  geom_text(aes(label = format(x= paste0(round(Values/1000000, 2), " mil t"))), 
            size = 3.3, position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9), hjust = -0.1) +
  labs(title = "Greenhouse gas emissions by sector, United States 2016") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.05))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 100000000, 300000000, 
                                500000000, 1000000000, 
                                1500000000, 2000000000),
                     labels = c("0", "100 mil", "300 mil", 
                                "500 mil", "1 bilion", 
                                "1.5 bilion", "2 bilion"), 
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0.15, 0.15))) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family = "sans", size = 9),
        title = element_text(size = 11, family = "sans", face = "bold"))
```

Photo of the bar plot (I don't have enough reputation to attach it to the post): https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuD4h.jpg

Also tried using `ggfittext` with `geom_bar_text', but with this solution I have a problem with size of the labels, and I have no clue how to change that.Also some of the values do not fit into the bars. Code below:

```
ggplot(USA, aes(x = Values, 
                y = fct_reorder(factor(Categories), Values),
                fill = Categories,
                label = format(x= paste0(round(Values/1000000, 2), " mil t")))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.65) +
  labs(title = "Greenhouse gas emissions by sector, United States 2016") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.05))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 100000000, 300000000, 
                                500000000, 1000000000, 
                                1500000000, 2000000000),
                     labels = c("0", "100 mil", "300 mil", 
                                "500 mil", "1 bilion", 
                                "1.5 bilion", "2 bilion"), 
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0.15, 0.15))) +
  geom_bar_text(position = "dodge") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family = "sans", size = 9),
        title = element_text(size = 11, family = "sans", face = "bold"))
```

Photo of the bar plot (with `geom_bar_text`):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yjIw.jpg

Comment: Please share your data using ``dput()`` and don't share it as an image.

Comment: You could set the alignment via a condition inside aes(): `geom_text(aes(..., hjust = ifelse(Values > 0, -.1, 1.1)), ...)`